# Passing env variables to script in command line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a perl module that gives me a string with key=value pairs that are meant to be used as environment variables to another script.
But when I do in the command line:

```
$(perl -I/foo -MFoo=vars -E'say vars()') script
```

I get errors from bash. How should I be using the command?

If I run:
`perl -I/foo -MFoo=vars -E'say vars()'` and then copy paste and run it works i.e.

`K1=V1 K2=V2 K3=V3 script`

I want to avoid having `export`

Comment: You cannot provide multi-line strings as as local env variables to command

Comment: @Inian: It is one line i.e. no new line chars

Comment: Ah! It could be a single long string with space separated k/v pairs, which bash treats as one long string. But in reality it needs separate arguments <k/v-1> <k/v-2> etc

Comment: @Inian: I am not sure I get what you mean by separate arguments

Comment: Could you paste the exact error shown?

Comment: What does the sentence _a perl module that gives me a string_. A module is **giving** a **string**? I don't think that a module can "give" anything.

Comment: I can see from _K1=V1 K2=V2 K3=V3 script_, that you set the environment variables K1, K2 and K3 for running a program named `script`,  but I don't see what's the problem is with this. _I want to avoid having export_ : There is no `export` command in your posting. I simply don't understand your problem here. Please provide a simple, reproducible example.

Comment: This is what `eval` is for. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/

Answer (score 4):

#### Problem

Bash can only accept key/value arguments local to the command as long as they are separate pairs and not a full string containing all the key/value pairs concatenated together,

i.e. if you have a script (`test.bash`) containing

```bash
echo "$FOO"
echo "$BAR"
```

and doing

```bash
FOO=foo BAR=bar bash test.bash
```

produces

```
foo
bar
```

but the same doesn't work, if you pass those key/value pairs as a single string. i.e.

```bash
x='FOO=foo BAR=bar'
"$x" bash test.bash
```

cannot work, because the order of shell expansions doesn't allow that. By the time the variable expansion of `x` happens, the command is evaluated with the expanded value as below. The re-processing of the command line variables doesn't happen again.

```bash
'FOO=foo BAR=bar' bash test.bash
```

which is not correct, as the whole literal string `'FOO=foo BAR=bar'` is treated as a one long command.

#### Solution

You could use the `env` command directly with the `-S` flag to pass each k/v pair into the environment, in which the `script` is run

```bash
env -S "$(perl -I/foo -MFoo=vars -E'say vars()')" script
```

By doing the above, each k/v pair in is added as additional environment variables to the shell in which the script is being run. Also note that `-S` is not portable (not POSIX compliant).